# How to add another field value to entry_options

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have 1 childtype which should get type fields value.

```
 $builder->add('rows', TableCollectionType::class, array(
     'entry_type' => HomeType::class,
     'entry_options' => ['test' => $test]
 ))
 ->add('type', HiddenType::class, [
     'constraints' => [
         new NotBlank(),
         new Choice(TypeClassifier::VALID_TYPES)
      ]
 ]);
```

tried to add eventlistener but unsuccessfully:

```
$form->get('rows')->add('edit_type', HiddenType::class, ['data' => $data['type']]);
```

Is there any possibility to pass `type` value to child type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to validate using that parameter. So fixed problem adding callback to parent type:

```
 $builder->add('rows', TableCollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => HomeType::class,
    'constraints' => [new Callback([$this, 'validateTest'])]
 ))
```

then in methode validateTest you can get type:

```
public function validateCosts($rows, ExecutionContext $context){
     $form = $context->getRoot();
     $data = $form->getData();
     $type = $data['type];
}
```